# Resizable <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-resizable

I have an element:

```
<a id="lnkViewEventDetails" class="psevdo calendar-event event" style="height: 126px;" href="/someurl/895?responseType=5" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
```

I want to make it resizable by using JQuery UI:

```
$("#lnkViewEventDetails").resizable();
```

But it doesn't work.

So what is the solution?

Answer (score 5):

`resizable()` only works on block elements. `A` is an inline element.

The style for this link needs to include `display:block;`